# Help with the interpretation of electron-positron pairs in Feynman diagrams for Thomson scattering, in terms of the Dirac "hole theory"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

[image]

I'm studying the Dirac theory for the electron, following Sakurai's Advanced Quantum Mechanics. Before even getting to the quantization of the Dirac field, the "hole theory" of a negative electron sea is presented, and some examples of its explanatory power are shown.

In particular, the correct cross section of the Thomson scattering is obtained by considering the different ways in which a "virtual positron" may be included in the process.

Now, the way I understand the left-hand diagram (fig. (a)) is: the incident photon $(\mathbf{k},\alpha)$ "escalates" one of the negative-energy electrons from the Dirac sea, creating an electron-positron pair. The electron $(\mathbf{p}',r')$ created in this process goes out and is detected as the scattered electron. The positron (the "hole" which corresponds to the absence of a $(\mathbf{p}'',r'')$ electron) then goes on to annihilate itself with the original (incident) electron, emmiting a $(\mathbf{k}',\alpha')$ photon, which is detected as the scattered photon.

My problem is with interpreting the right-hand diagram (fig. (b)). The way Sakurai describes it is:

> "[...] Fig. 3-6(b), which physically represents the creation of an
> electron-positron pair plus the outgoing photon followed by the
> annihilation of the positron with the initial electron and the
> incident photon."

So, it appears that the electron-positron pair is created "with" the outgoing photon? "By" the outgoing photon? I thought that pair creation required the absorption of a photon, and annihilation required the emmission of a photon. But here it seems that the pair creation emmits a photon (the outgoing, scattered photon).

I guess a more "naive" but equivalent way of posing the question is:
I understand both the annihilation and the creation of electron-positron pairs as the convergence of an "$e^-$" line and an "$e^+$" line into a photon squiggly line. But how do I interpret the squiggly line going into the same direction of the electron-positron pair?